# Why do I need to set permissions when calling OpenFile?

Tags: go

I understand what permissions mean for files and dirs stored in filesystem.
But why do I need to set permissions **when calling os.OpenFile**?
Does it update file permission on filesystem if opened successfully?
If not - what difference does it make to open same file with 0000 or 0777?

https://golang.org/src/os/file.go?s=8454:8520#L272

```
func OpenFile(name string, flag int, perm FileMode) (*File, error)
...
f, err := os.OpenFile("access.log", os.O_APPEND, 0644)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [documented](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile) (emphasis added):

> OpenFile is the generalized open call; most users will use Open or Create instead. It opens the named file with specified flag (O_RDONLY etc.) and **perm (before umask), if applicable**. If successful, methods on the returned File can be used for I/O. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

So, the `perm` value is only used when the file is created--when opening an existing file, it is not applicable, so it is ignored.